# Help me identify this weed growing in my lawn

Tags: lawn, weeds

It is 'branchy' and lies low evading the lawn mower. Do you know what it is?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like creeping buttercup (*Ranunculus repens*) to me. If you get any yellow flowers, that would confirm the identification.

See https://www.lawnweeds.co.uk/weed-identification/creeping-buttercup for some pictures.

It spreads rapidly by putting out runners, so getting rid of it "without using chemicals" is not easy. A broad-leaf lawn weedkiller should work but you may need more than one application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm happy it's just not something more sinister like Japanese knot weed!